# Batch get variable's value

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%p in (input.txt) do (
echo %%p
cd %%p
set /a c = 0
for %%f in (*) do (
echo %%f
if not exist *test*.* (
set /a c += 1
)
)
if %%c GTR 0 echo %%p >>folders.txt
cd ..
)
```

But the last if statement is not working. I want to know what do I have to do to have access to the variable c that I set up in the first for. I've tried different combinations like !c! or %c% but nothing seems to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems here:

1. No spaces must be around the `=` in `set`:

   ```
   set c=0
   set /a c+=1
   ```

   Otherwise you're creating a variable whose name ends in a space.
2. You cannot set variables in a block and use them in the same block again without using delayed expansion. So you need

   ```
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   ```

   at the start of your batch file and then use `!c!` instead of `%%c` (which in itself is wrong already because variables of the `%%x` form are `for` loop variables, not environment variables you set with `set` – but `%%p` is correct because it *is* a `for` loop variable).

   Delayed expansion is necessary because `cmd` will expand variables to their values as soon as a statement is *parsed*, not directly prior to its execution. And the whole block of your `for` loop is a single statement as far as `cmd` is concerned, thus when the loop runs any environment variables are already expanded to their values.

So you'll end with

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%p in (input.txt) do (
  echo %%p
  pushd %%p
  set /a c=0
  for %%f in (*) do (
    echo %%f
    if not exist *test*.* (
      set /a c+=1
    )
  )
  if !c! GTR 0 echo %%p >>folders.txt
  popd
)
```

(I also used `pushd`/`popd` instead of `cd` to change directories which is a little nicer.)

Comment: It's right, spaces should be avoided, but `set /a` will remove the spaces itself, so `set /a c=0` and `set /a c  =  0` are equivalent

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now. I am new to this, and I don't know all the rules yet. So thanks for explaining.

Comment: jeb: Ok, I vaguely remembered as much, but imho it's best in this case to not let bad habits slip in and bite you later if you use a `set` without `/a` :)